# Full Width Material-UI Grid not working as it should

Tags: css, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I am trying to understand Material-UI@next grid layout system.

My goal is to have two papers that expand through the whole width screen and break whenever the screen gets smaller to just one paper. The [documentation](https://material-ui-next.com/layout/grid/) has the following code snippet:

```
  <Container>
    <Grid container spacing={24}>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Paper>xs=12</Paper>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
        <Paper>xs=12 sm=6</Paper>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
        <Paper>xs=12 sm=6</Paper>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
        <Paper>xs=6 sm=3</Paper>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
        <Paper>xs=6 sm=3</Paper>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
        <Paper>xs=6 sm=3</Paper>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
        <Paper>xs=6 sm=3</Paper>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </Container>
```

This results in the following:
[image]

I then modified the code to try to achieve my goal of just two papers, as this:

```
  <Container>
    <Grid container spacing={24}>
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
        <Paper>xs=12 sm=6</Paper>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
        <Paper>xs=12 sm=6</Paper>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </Container>
```

But as you can see, this results into two papers which are not taking the whole screen:
[image]

Can someone point me to a working example snippet that allows me to have two elements that take the full width?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I suspect the Container component is causing you problems. Since you haven't linked its implementation, see below for a working example of what you want.

Since Material uses [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) they make use of property [flexGrow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow)

> The flex-grow CSS property specifies the flex grow factor of a flex item. It specifies what amount of space inside the flex container the item should take up. The flex grow factor of a flex item is relative to the size of the other children in the flex-container.

This is the property that governs the growth of elements in the grid.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
import Grid from 'material-ui/Grid';

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
  },
});

function CenteredGrid(props) {
  const { classes } = props;

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
        <Grid container spacing={24}>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
            <Paper>xs=12 sm=6</Paper>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
            <Paper>xs=12 sm=6</Paper>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}

CenteredGrid.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(CenteredGrid);
```

Comment: I don't get the role of your  flex-grow:1  here. It works for flex items only and here this div is a top level tag...
Working example without it... https://codesandbox.io/s/mm2vwpljr9

Comment: @Tomek I don't see the spacing working on your example.

Comment: thanks man ... yet i don't think id needs flexGrow

Answer (score 5):

Best practice is to test out all break points and specify the allocation of space for each screen width.

```
<Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={6} xl={4}>

</Grid>
```

> xs, extra small 0px

> sm, small: 600px

> md, medium: 960px

> lg, large: 1280px.

> xl,extra-large: 1920px

https://material-ui.com/customization/breakpoints/

**xs** Defines the number of grids the component is going to use. It's applied for all the screen sizes with the lowest priority.

**sm** Defines the number of grids the component is going to use. It's applied for the sm breakpoint and wider screens if not overridden.

**md** Defines the number of grids the component is going to use. It's applied for the md breakpoint and wider screens if not overridden.

(and so forth)
more here: https://material-ui.com/api/grid/

Answer (score 2):

For those using Material UI with `styled-components`, here's how I was able to get the grid items to grow correctly:

```
import GridBase from "@material-ui/core/Grid";

const Grid = styled(GridBase)`
  .MuiGrid-root {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
`
```

Now you can use `Grid` normally in your components.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old question , but just want to share.

The problem from your code is **`spacing={24}`**
based on documentation [Spacing](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#spacing)  . By default, the spacing between two grid items follows a linear function: `output(spacing) = spacing * 8px`

e.g. **spacing={24}** creates a **192px** wide gap. so at the end ,  the space available for the content very small.

```
<Grid container spacing={2}> //  usually 2 or 3  is quite enough for me
  <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
    <Paper>xs=12 sm=6</Paper>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
    <Paper>xs=12 sm=6</Paper>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was also experiencing this issue. What solved it for me is using the "sx" property to make the width of the parent grid = 100%. See code below:

```
<Box sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
<Button variant="contained" fullWidth> myButton </Button>
</Box>
```