MUI Grid Width/ CSS issue
To be honest I am not sure, what is causing the problem, but I am trying to use MaterialUI and its not occupying the full width and I am not sure what is causing this issue. I have tried a lot of things and nothing seems to work. I think the min-width property is messing the whole page:
output
CSS properties from the browser debugger
My app.css
body {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  justify-content: center;
  min-width: 100%;
}

My app.jsx
import { useState } from "react";
import MaterialForm from "./components/MaterialForm";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <MaterialForm />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

My form:
import React, { useState } from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";

export default function MaterialForm() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    legalFirstName: "",
    legalLastName: "",
    email: "",
    contactNumber: "",
    
  });

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Handle form submission here
    console.log(formData);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} style={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <TextField
            fullWidth
            label="Legal First Name (As mentioned in Passport)"
            variant="outlined"
            name="legalFirstName"
            value={formData.legalFirstName}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <TextField
            fullWidth
            label="Legal Last Name (As mentioned in Passport)"
            variant="outlined"
            name="legalLastName"
            value={formData.legalLastName}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <TextField
            fullWidth
            label="Email"
            variant="outlined"
            name="email"
            value={formData.email}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <TextField
            fullWidth
            label="Contact Number"
            variant="outlined"
            name="contactNumber"
            value={formData.contactNumber}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </form>
  );
}

I have tried multiple CSS changes and editing the grid item size and spacing as well but nothing is working

this may be related to using Mui Grid Container https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49797264/full-width-material-ui-grid-not-working-as-it-should

Hi I actually did refer to that link but our problems are not related

can you link a minimum working example so i can take a look

@snackoverflow I am new to posting questions, what do you mean by working example?
if you are asking for an output image then its on my question link and is called output
